# Unity editorTestsFilter command line argument not working

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-test-tools

Please tell me what is wrong with this command line for build android application in Unity with run tests with [Unity Test] attribute:

**"C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Unity.exe" -editorTestsFilter MyTestName -runTests -projectPath "C:\Projects\ProjectName\" -testResults "C:\results.xml" -testPlatform playmode**

Unity runs all tests, but I need to run selected one.

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: There is a `_` where a \ should be

Answer (score 0):

This is an active issue with Unity unfortunately. As far as I can tell your command is fine.

See: [Unity Issue Trcker ID: 1008728](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/unitytestrunner-editortestsfilter-and-editortestscategories-command-line-arguments-dont-work-in-batchmode)